# LOST.DIR folder appears all the time in my tablet

Tags: tablet

I have Silver-Line tablet SL-1066 model. 
When I connect USB stick or SD card the tablet always create a folder 
under the name "LOST.DIR" and the folder is empty.
this folder is also appear in my computer when I connect USB or SD card, this is also appear in my computer after the tablet created it. 
I tried always to delete it, but if I connect the device to the tablet again, it is will recreate the folder.

Someone know how to make it never to create this folder again?

Thank you!

Comment: The questions here are expected to show*at least* a bare minimum effort to [search the problem over web](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=what+is+LOST.DIR). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The "LOST.DIR" is a System Folder, and Android creates it on boot. It is used to recover any files that you may have lost due to an unexpected shutdown (i.e. you run out of battery) or because you pulled an SD-CARD out without unmounting it first. You can keep deleting this folder, but Android OS will be just as persistent in recreating it :) 
 
Think about it like the Recycling Bin in Windows, you can't get rid of it no matter how hard you try!

Comment: Ohh.. it is very strange, because i heard about someone deleted the "LOST.DIR" folder with Tasker app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm

I don't know how to do it, but i heard it is possible.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I have never use Tasker before, so unfortunately I can not help with that. I would recommend asking a new question on how to delete LOST.DIR with tasker (or just ask how to delete directories with tasker?)